# Does windows phone application submitted for inhouse reviewed by microsoft?

Tags: windows-phone-7, distribution

We are planning to release The application internally to client(Similar to over the air of iphone),for internal release **does Application need to be reviewed by Microsoft**?

Before asking here i have gone through [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206724%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
But they havent mentioned any info on company's internal release(without app store)

Hoping for answers...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Company app distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). When application is distributed in that way it bypasses Windows Phone Store and its certification.

There is also Beta version submission available within Windows Phone Store which does not require certification: [Beta testing your app and in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)